# Adding new rows on a button click

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add new row on a button click but i cant figured it out how comes the button only added at the top

here is the code

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    Dim unitsSheet As Worksheet
    Set unitsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Units") ' Change "Units" to the name of your Units sheet

    ' Find the last used row in column A
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Calculate the next row to insert
    Dim nextRow As Long
    nextRow = lastRow + 1

    ' Insert four new rows at the calculated position
    ws.Rows(nextRow).Resize(4).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    ' Merge each column (A to O) separately for the four rows
    Dim col As Integer
    For col = 1 To 15 ' Columns A to O
        With ws
            .Range(.Cells(nextRow, col), .Cells(nextRow + 3, col)).Merge
        End With

        ' Insert "From Unit" in the first cell of column Q for each column
        ws.Cells(nextRow, 17).Value = "From Unit"

        ' Insert "Qty" in the second cell of column Q for each column
        ws.Cells(nextRow + 1, 17).Value = "Qty"

        ' Insert "To Unit" in the third cell of column Q for each column
        ws.Cells(nextRow + 2, 17).Value = "To Unit"

        ' Insert "Selling Price" in the fourth cell of column Q for each column
        ws.Cells(nextRow + 3, 17).Value = "Selling Price"

        ' Determine the appropriate column (R, S, T, U, V, etc.) for copying data from the "Units" sheet
        Dim destinationColumn As String
        destinationColumn = Chr(82 + col) ' Convert column index to letter (R, S, T, U, V, etc.)

        ' Calculate the corresponding row in the "Units" sheet
        Dim unitsRow As Long
        unitsRow = nextRow - lastRow + 2

        ' Copy values from the "Units" sheet and populate them into the appropriate column
        ws.Cells(nextRow, col + 17).Value = unitsSheet.Cells(unitsRow, 1).Value
    Next col
```

I was expecting the row to be added at the bottom but it added at the top

here is what i am expecting

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ98Z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ98Z.png)

Comment: `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`: looks like your column A is empty except for maybe a header?

Comment: Maybe try `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 1):

Please exercise caution when obtaining the last data row in a column with merged cells.

- The value of `lastRow` is `5` instead of `8`.
- `nextRow = lastRow + 1` is not the right position to insert rows.
- `ws.Rows(nextRow).Resize(4).Insert` expands the merged area.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print lastRow  ' Output is 5
    Dim nextRow As Long
    nextRow = lastRow + 1
    ws.Rows(nextRow).Resize(4).Insert Shift:=xlDown 
    ' *********************
    ' -- Revised code
    Dim nextRow As Long
    nextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).MergeArea.Offset(1).Row
    Debug.Print nextRow' Ouput is 9
    ' Don't need insert rows before merging
    Dim col As Integer
    For col = 1 To 15 ' Columns A to O
        With ws
            .Range(.Cells(nextRow, col), .Cells(nextRow + 3, col)).Merge
        End With
    ' Your code
    Next col
End Sub
```